# How to listen for input from a physical keypad using android?

Tags: android

The hardware I am working with is powered by android and has a physical keypad (1-9, Clear, Enter, F1-F8). I'm trying to make the program respond to key press, but I'm having trouble.

I've tried logging the button press through onKeyDown and listening for what key code is returned, but no luck. I don't think android can tell that this is a keyboard. (interestingly, when I press F1-F12 on the virtual emulator I also don't get any response, but as long as I can read input on the hardware device that's all I need. Might these keys respond to something different?)

Is there any other way to listen for user input through hardware?

Comment: If this is custom hardware, then I guess the best source of information is the documentation for that hardware. It would be reasonable to expect that hardware key presses are injected into the framework through `onKeyDown()`/`onKeyUp()`, but if it's not the case - only the documentation can tell how to handle those.

Comment: If your device manufacturer is the one who put Android on this hardware, your device manufacturer should be able to tell you how to receive key input. It would seem odd for a device sporting a keypad to not have a way for Android apps to respond to the keypad.